# Custom Spellchecker Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a simple javascript code for a text area, which should spell check the words in the text area with custom word list (medical words).  I have a word list with more than 5000 medical words and I want to use that as the custom list.  After comparing with the custom list, if the spelling is wrong, it should provide suggestions from the custom list, so that you can correct in the text area.

Are there any javascripts out there for this?  I tried BJspell, but there is no option to add custom words.

Comment: It is possible to use BJspell with custom dictionary. Just look at the source, read comments then examine the structure of the language file so you can build your own word list. https://code.google.com/p/bjspell/downloads/list

Comment: Thank you!  I think I overlooked it.  I will go through it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

1) try this https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-spellchecker

here is a sample http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/

2) try this http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/

Comment: I want to add custom dictionary or list of words.  As far as I read, I don't think it is possible with option 1.  Thank you for the links!